# How to show search results with UISearchResultsUpdating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, search

I've been reading a lot about the new UISearchController and its protocols. and I saw many pages in the documentation also the sample code from Apple. But I couldn't implement it in my project -Xcode 6.4- iOS 8 App.

Right now I need help on implementing the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol.
I've made `UITableViewController` called `FYPBooksLibraryTableViewController` and I want to search its file names. When I run it everything works, BUT the results are not shown at all.

From .m file:

```
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchResultsUpdating
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
//Waiting a fix
}
```

**My data are in those 2 files: BooksData & FYPBooksObject**

```
    //  BooksData.h

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    #define BOOK_NAME @"Book Name"
    #define BOOK_NUMBER_OF_PAGES @"Number of Pages"
    #define BOOK_LINK @"Book Path"

    @interface BooksData : NSObject
    + (NSArray *)allBooks;
    @end

    //  BooksData.m
    #import "BooksData.h"

    @implementation BooksData
    + (NSArray *)allBooks {
        NSMutableArray *booksInformation = [@[] mutableCopy];
        NSDictionary *book1Dictionary = @{BOOK_NAME : @"Book 1", BOOK_NUMBER_OF_PAGES : @"Number of pages: 43", BOOK_LINK : @"http://www.example.com/file.pdf"};
        [booksInformation addObject:book1Dictionary];

    ...

    return [booksInformation copy];
    }

    @end

    //FYPBooksObject.h

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @interface FYPBooksObject : NSObject

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameB;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *numberOfPagesB;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlBook;

    -(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;

    @end

    //FYPBooksObject.m
        #import "FYPBooksObject.h"
        #import "BooksData.h"

        @implementation FYPBooksObject
        -(id)init {
            self = [self initWithData:nil];
            return self;
        }
        -(id)initWithData:(NSDictionary *)data {
            self = [super init];
            self.nameB = data[BOOK_NAME];
            self.numberOfPagesB = data[BOOK_NUMBER_OF_PAGES];
            self.urlBook = data[BOOK_LINK];
            return self;
        }

@end
```

Please bear with me and give me a full solution to search and display the results for books names in the same table view controller.
And if there is a way to do an online search inside the books I'll appreciated..

Comment: You should remove all these empty delegate calls, as they do nothing and make code less readable, forces users to read extra lines, so they're slower to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, and I had to rebuild the app structure. sample code from GitHub helped me to do that. Here is the link: https://github.com/dempseyatgithub/Sample-UISearchController